# How to load files that are specified in a .txt file?(python)

Tags: python, numpy, file

I tried to use this code, but it keeps saying that the file is not found and all of them are in the same folder. Thanks for your help!

```py
import numpy as np

with open('datasort.txt') as t:
    lines = t.readlines()
    
for i in lines:
    x= np.loadtxt(i)
```

Comment: Case sensitivity?

Comment: Since each line in t.readlines() has a trailing '\n', try: `np.loadtxt(i.rstrip())` to get rid of the '\n' in each file name read.

Comment: This isn't a `numpy` issue.  Some how or other you need to get the right directory and/or filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the complete path to the file. For example:

`with open('\BigFolder\LittleFolder\datasort.txt') as t: lines = t.readlines()`